# Can I redirect a c# class to another dll?

Tags: c#, overriding, version, libraries

Here is my problem. There is a game engine with a core library core2.dll which has a class C in it.

It is a windows class with a c# wrapper.

I want to use mainly all the classes from core2.dll except for one class which I want to use the class from the previous version of the library core1.dll

If you try to call the class from core2.dll it has a 'deprecated error message'.

I think the class is pretty self contained. (Lets say it is some math functions for example) So my thoughts are to include both core2.dll and core1.dll in my project but somehow make the class C only from core1.dll.

Any thoughts on how (if at all ) to achieve this?

Comment: Yes. you can. You can reference both DLL versions into different namespaces and have both version classes available. Your question would be more interesting if you would put some code to show what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks @T.S. I'm not really an expert in C# have you got an example?

Comment: what example? This VS function. You add reference. But default it is goes into `global::`. In the solution explorer on the reference properties there is field `aliases`. If you set alias for ddl (v1), you set alias like `dll_v1`. Then in code `var a = new dll_v1::myclass();`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand I'm afraid. :(

Comment: If you do this, you will have two versions of *all* the classes. There is no guarantee they will interoperate.

Comment: @John Wu. Yes I only need one class out of the old dll which I hope is fairly self contained and doesn't call any other classes.

Comment: of course - yes and of course - not. But if you want to use `v1cls.Method1` for something and then `v2cls.Method2` in other instances - you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to replace part of the code inside core2.dll then you can decompile both using ildasm, change required pieces inside core2.dll and compile it back again.

Run `x64_x86 Cross Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017` and execute

```
ildasm core1.dll /OUT=core1.il
ildasm core2.dll /OUT=core2.il


REM open il files with text editor, find classes in core1.il and replace them in core2.il 
REM note, that there might be no core2.res

ilasm core2.il /RESOURCE=core2.res /DLL
```

This will work absolutely fine if dll is not signed. Even better - you assemble to code so ilasm will ensure your code will work in the runtime. Runtime incompatibility is a pretty annoying issue with binding redirects...

Make sure you don't violate any licenses and copyrights.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use external alias for both dll

here is an example:
https://www.learningsomethingnew.com/how-to-use-two-versions-of-the-same-dll-in-the-same-project

Comment: OK. I see. I am using Unity so I'm wondering if it is possible to do it there. I think Unity automataically imports the dlls. So I don't know how much control there is over it.